# programmatically populate and open a bootstrap dropdown when clicked and empty it when closed

Tags: javascript, html, jquery, bootstrap-4

is there a way to display the dropdown content only when clicked instead of displaying all of the content on the run and adding more html lines?

like make an `onclick` attrib on the button and put a function inside??

```js
var data = [{
  "id": 104,
  "note": "[\"copyright striked\"]",
  "status_color": "primary"
}, {
  "id": 49,
  "note": "[]",
  "status_color": "primary"
}, {
  "id": 105,
  "note": "[\"officially translated\"]",
  "status_color": "secondary"
}, {
  "id": 43,
  "note": "[]",
  "status_color": "primary"
}, {
  "id": 48,
  "note": "[\"Waiting for after credits\"]",
  "status_color": "warning"
}];

// console.log(data);
for (let row of data) {
  let uid = row.id;
  let notes = row.note;
  let color = row.status_color;

  $('#collection').append(html_card(uid, notes, color));
} //end of for-loop


function html_card(id, notes, color) {
  let append = '';
  append += '<div class="">';
  if (notes != '[]') {
    append += '<div class="dropdown">';
    append += '<button class="btn btn-outline-' + color + ' text-left rounded-pill px-2 py-0 mr-3"';
    append += ' role="button" data-toggle="dropdown" aria-expanded="false">';
    append += 'See Notes<span class="bi bi-sticky ml-1"></span></button>';
    append += '<ul class="dropdown-menu dropdown-menu-right">';
    for (let note of JSON.parse(notes)) {
      append += '<li class="dropdown-item-text pr-2">&raquo; ' + note + '</li>';
    }
    append += '</ul>';
    append += '</div>';
  }
  append += '</div>';
  return append;
}
```

```html
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/bootstrap@4.6.1/dist/css/bootstrap.min.css" integrity="sha384-zCbKRCUGaJDkqS1kPbPd7TveP5iyJE0EjAuZQTgFLD2ylzuqKfdKlfG/eSrtxUkn" crossorigin="anonymous">
<script src="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/jquery@3.5.1/dist/jquery.slim.min.js" integrity="sha384-DfXdz2htPH0lsSSs5nCTpuj/zy4C+OGpamoFVy38MVBnE+IbbVYUew+OrCXaRkfj" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
<script src="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/popper.js@1.16.1/dist/umd/popper.min.js" integrity="sha384-9/reFTGAW83EW2RDu2S0VKaIzap3H66lZH81PoYlFhbGU+6BZp6G7niu735Sk7lN" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
<script src="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/bootstrap@4.6.1/dist/js/bootstrap.min.js" integrity="sha384-VHvPCCyXqtD5DqJeNxl2dtTyhF78xXNXdkwX1CZeRusQfRKp+tA7hAShOK/B/fQ2" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/bootstrap-icons@1.8.3/font/bootstrap-icons.css">

<div id="collection" class='row justify-content-center px-2 my-3'></div>
```

*note:* i wanna make a very compact design and the dropdown is the only work around that i can see in bootstrap

here's the [JSFiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/dkc1pfmr/)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Do you mean something like this :

```js
var data = [{
  "id": 104,
  "note": "[\"copyright striked\", \"copyright v2\"]",
  "status_color": "primary"
}, {
  "id": 49,
  "note": "[]",
  "status_color": "primary"
}, {
  "id": 105,
  "note": "[\"officially translated\"]",
  "status_color": "secondary"
}, {
  "id": 43,
  "note": "[]",
  "status_color": "primary"
}, {
  "id": 48,
  "note": "[\"Waiting for after credits\"]",
  "status_color": "warning"
}];

//console.log(data);
for (let row of data) {
  let uid = row.id;
  let notes = row.note;
  let color = row.status_color;

  $('#collection').append(html_card(uid, notes, color));
} //end of for-loop


function html_card(id, notes, color) {
  let append = '';
  if (notes != '[]') {
    append += '<div class="dropdown float-right">';
    append += '<button id=' + id + ' class="btn btn-outline-' + color + ' text-left rounded-pill px-2 py-0 mr-3"';
    append += ` role="button" data-toggle="dropdown" 
                    onClick="getNotes(&apos;` + encodeURIComponent(JSON.stringify(notes)) + `&apos; , ` + id + `);
            " aria-expanded="false">`;
    append += 'See Notes<span class="bi bi-sticky ml-1"></span></button>';
    append += '<ul class="dropdown-menu dropdown-menu-right">';
    append += '</ul>';
    append += '</div>';
  }
  return append;
}

function getNotes(notes, _this) {
if($("#" + _this).parent().find(".dropdown-menu").html() === '')
  for (let note of JSON.parse(JSON.parse(decodeURIComponent(notes)))) {
    $("#" + _this).parent().find(".dropdown-menu")
      .append('<li class="dropdown-item-text pr-2">&raquo; ' + note + '</li>')
  }
}
```

```html
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/bootstrap@4.6.1/dist/css/bootstrap.min.css" integrity="sha384-zCbKRCUGaJDkqS1kPbPd7TveP5iyJE0EjAuZQTgFLD2ylzuqKfdKlfG/eSrtxUkn" crossorigin="anonymous">
<script src="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/jquery@3.5.1/dist/jquery.slim.min.js" integrity="sha384-DfXdz2htPH0lsSSs5nCTpuj/zy4C+OGpamoFVy38MVBnE+IbbVYUew+OrCXaRkfj" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
<script src="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/popper.js@1.16.1/dist/umd/popper.min.js" integrity="sha384-9/reFTGAW83EW2RDu2S0VKaIzap3H66lZH81PoYlFhbGU+6BZp6G7niu735Sk7lN" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
<script src="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/bootstrap@4.6.1/dist/js/bootstrap.min.js" integrity="sha384-VHvPCCyXqtD5DqJeNxl2dtTyhF78xXNXdkwX1CZeRusQfRKp+tA7hAShOK/B/fQ2" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/bootstrap-icons@1.8.3/font/bootstrap-icons.css">

<div id="collection" class='row justify-content-center px-2 my-3'></div>
```

I hope this helps

Comment: yes YES IT'S EXACTLY THIS! thank you kind sir! i never thought this was possible because the popper.js's `.dropdown` was throwing errors since i removed the `<ul>` tag.

Comment: happy I could help you =)